# Iterate through Dictionary of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got pretty stuck on the basic idea of DataFrames within dictionaries.

Could someone please explain to me how they would iterate through a dict and select specific columns in a DataFrame while still keeping in mind time complexity?

For that reason I created a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.randint(5, 30, size=(10,3))
df_APPL = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Volume', 'Open', 'Close'])
df_TSLA = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Volume', 'Open', 'Close'])
df_AMZN = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Volume', 'Open', 'Close'])

d = {'APPL': df_APPL,
     'TSLA': df_TSLA,
     'AMZN': df_AMZN}
```

In this basic example, how would I select `'Open'` in every DataFrame and sort the keys from max to min according to `'Open'`?

Any other example would also be welcome. `:)`

Comment: you want to sort dataframes based on `Open` column and append all the dataframes?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to sort the DFs. I would just like to grasp the concept on how to select columns within dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort_values()` to sort dataframe based on a column values:

see more about `sort_values()` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

```
nd = {k:v.sort_values('Open', ascending=False) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how to generally select those columns in the dict?

Comment: sort_values() takes a column name and sort the rows based on that column values. It will first sort the column values itself and then sort the column values of other column based on it. see more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)